# Examples of exotic (non-)norms?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

What are some "out of the box" examples of functionals on some mainstream vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $C^0([0, 1])$, for which determining whether or not they are a norm is not exactly straightforward?

On the spot I can only think of $A(x, y)=\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The $p$-adic norms would certainly qualify, but I'm looking more for some nice closed-form functionals.

Answer (score 3):

Take any expression of the form $\Vert Ax \Vert_p$, where $A$ is invertible matrix. By expanding this, it will become "unobvious" that we are facing a norm.

Your example is of this form with $p=2$ and $$A(x,y)=\left(x -\frac{y}{2}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}y\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ and $F$ be a normed vector spaces and $A: \mathbb{R} \mapsto L(E, F)$ be a continuous family of bounded linear maps such that
$$
\bigcap_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \ker A(t) = \{ 0 \}.
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \|A(t)\|_{L(E, F)}dt < \infty.
$$
Then
$$
x \in E \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}\|A(t)x\|_Fdt
$$
is a norm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you consider $A_n(x,y)=(x^{2n}+y^{2n})^{1/{2n}}$ for certain $n>1$ family of norms as "out of the box"?

To be honest they seem fairly "mainstream" but I am interested in them and I have no idea if they have been already studied or how to address them in my searches.

Comment: This is just the $p$-norm on $\mathbb R^2$ for $p=2n$. So yes, pretty mainstream indeed.